# Spark Using Disk Resources When Memory is Available

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-mllib, emr

I'm working on optimizing the performance of my Spark cluster (run on AWS EMR) that is performing Collaborative Filtering using the ALS matrix factorization algorithm.  We are using quite a few factors and iterations so I'm trying to optimize these steps in particular.  I am trying to understand why I am using disk space when I have plenty of memory available. Here is the total cluster memory available:

[image]

Here is the remaining disk space (notice the dips of disk utilization):

[image]

I've tried looking at the Yarn manager and it looks like it shows that each node slave has: 110 GB (used)   4 GB (avail.).  You can also see the total allocated on the first image (700 GB).  I've also tried changing the ALS source and forcing the `intermediateRDDStorageLevel` and `finalRDDStorageLevel` from MEMORY_AND_DISK to MEMORY_ONLY and that didn't affect anything.

I am not persisting my RDD's anywhere else in my code so I'm not sure where this disk utilization is coming from.  I'd like to better utilize the resources on my cluster, any ideas?  How can I more effectively use the available memory?

Comment: Spark is not supposed to take entire YARN capacity. It takes how much has been allocated as driver and executor memory. How much did you allocate for them ?

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya I've tried everything from 20Gb to 40Gb and it doesn't seem to change the usage.  Should I be submitting multiple yarn applications concurrently? (I'm not worried about driver memory at this point as I submit in client mode and the driver looks good as far as memory usage is concerned).

Comment: Another thing, spark only uses a small part of the available memory for caching data. spark. Memory. Fraction is the configuration you can tweak. If you don't have shuffle operation try to increase the fraction of spark. memory. fraction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be few scenerios where spark will be using the disk usage instead of memory

1. If you have shuffle operation. Spark writes the shuffled data in the disk only so if you have shuffle operation you are out of luck
2. Low executor memory. If you have low executor memory spark has less memory to keep the data so it will be spilling the data from memory to disk. However as you suggested you have tried executor memory from 20G to 40G. I will recommend to keep the executor memory till 40G as beyoind that JVM GC could make your process slower.
3. If you don't have shuffle operation you might as well tweak `spark.memory.fraction` if you are using spark 2.2

From [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management)

`spark.memory.fraction` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management)) expresses the size of M as a fraction of the (JVM heap space - 300MB) (default 0.6). The rest of the space (40%)
is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually
large records.

So you can make the spark.memory.fraction to .9 and see the behavior.

4. Lastly there are options apart from `MEMORY_ONLY` as storage level like `MEMORY_ONLY_SER` which will serialize the data and store in memory. This option reduces the memory usage as serialized object size is much smaller than the actual object size. If you see lot of spill you can opt this storage level.

Comment: I have shuffle operations, and it sounds like those are only on-disk, so I suppose there is nothing to optimize there.  Thanks!